# VCL custom TGraphicControl messes up only on a remote desktop

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, remote-desktop, c++builder-10.3-rio

In a C++ application (using C++Builder 10.3 and VCL), I use a custom class derived from `TGraphicControl` to draw a custom user interface and a small plot of changing data.

Everything works well in Windows 10 and Windows 7, but if I execute the application in a Remote Desktop session (via a native Windows service) with each redraw the graphics are messed up more.

The problem starts with disappearing elements and wrong `LineTo` endpoints, but sometimes the elements appear even in a different dialog instead.

Also, switching on a PC from direct to remote access causes dynamically inserted VCL `TComboBox` elements to get invalid parents and owners, followed by an error message that the `TComboBox` class is unknown.

I'm using `ClientRect` in my code. Is this perhaps the problem when working in remote sessions?

Code where I see the problem (it's a bit long and I have trouble making a minimal example without omitting possible causes of the problem)
cpp: https://pastebin.com/vpk3De7J (painter at line 228)
header: https://pastebin.com/3pLy4dEY

```cpp
class CustomTrgDrawings : public TGraphicControl
{
private:
    void __fastcall Paint(void);
public:
    __fastcall CustomTrgDrawings(TComponent* Owner);
    bool updating;      //stops painting when true
}; 

__fastcall CustomTrgDrawings::CustomTrgDrawings(TComponent* Owner)
    : TGraphicControl(Owner)
{
    updating = true;
}

void __fastcall CustomTrgDrawings::Paint(void)
{
    if (!updating)
        return;

    Canvas->Brush->Color = TColor(0x220022);
    Canvas->Brush->Style = bsSolid;
    Canvas->Pen->Color = TColor(0x222222);
    Canvas->Pen->Style = psSolid;
    Canvas->Pen->Width = 1;

    Canvas->FillRect(ClientRect);
}

//---insertion in a vcl form
void __fastcall TMyForm::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    //uses TLabel *myLabel as container
    CustomTrgDrawings *drg = new CustomTrgDrawings(myLabel);
}
```

Comment: You did not show your complete drawing code, so how can we see if you are drawing things correctly to begin with? Your symptoms suggest possible memory corruption is occurring, especially since other classes are being affected. Also, where are you setting the control's `Parent`? It is not enough to just set its `Owner`. Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the same problem in action.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for the suggestions! The code I posted is already leading to the error. So I think it is already a minimal example. Just the code for the second form is missing. But no other code preparing/inserting the custom class was done. I will check for memory corruption, set the Parent and see if this solves the problem.

Comment: There is no possible way the code you have shown *as-is* can cause the issue you describe. But your code states "*other Canvas Fill/Draw/LineTo operations*", so how do we know those "other operations" aren't at fault? As for the `Parent`, how do you expect your control to be seen by the user if there is no `Parent` to display it? Assigning an `Owner` is only for memory management. Assigning a `Parent` is required for visual placement. Without a `Parent`, your control is not shown onscreen, and thus is never painted, so it wouldn't matter what its drawing code looks like if it is never called.

Comment: I went through the code and tried to make a more complete minimal-example, but it's difficult for me without omitting things. But I saw that the deriving class is setting its parent to the placeholder-owner when I was working on that. So at least the Parent is correct (I think? ^^). I added links to code snippets where I removed not-relevant classes to make it more minimal, but still runnable and hopefully not omitting the cause of the error. However, if I run snippet above, I also get this behavior. Your initial guess with memory corruption somewhere else seems more likely.